# Using scanf in assembly SASM to receive input to register and not a stack

Tags: assembly, scanf, x86-64

Hi I'm new to assembly and SASM,
can I write something like this?

```
movq $char, %rdi   
movq %rdx, %rsi  
xor %rax, %rax    
call scanf   
movzbq (%rdx), %rcx
```

And then get the char value for rcx?
Thanks!

Comment: Depends on how you set up `rdx`, yes. The input has to go into memory first (doesn't have to be the stack though). Note that `rdx` is caller-saved, so you can't rely on it having the same value after `scanf` returns. You will have to reload.

Comment: So if I understand correctly I have to allocate stack location (increment rsp) and then get the address to my user's input from there?
I'm a bit confused because we were instructed not to use stack unless we have too, and I thought this code upstairs will do the job, and not use the stack...
correct me if I'm wrong...

Comment: You can use any memory, not just stack. The code above is missing the initialization of `rdx`. Note that `movzbq (%rdx), %rcx` is also using it as a pointer. You definitely need to load a valid pointer into it first. Also if the requirement is to read a character without stack usage, you can `call getchar` instead of `scanf`. PS: even `call` uses the stack for the return address of course. PPS: you allocate by **decrementing** not incrementing.

Comment: can you please elaborate on how you would write it?
depending that we have to use scanf and avoid out of stack memory access?
And I don't suppose to care about the initializtion of rdx as he is caller saved, isn't it?

Comment: You must make `rdx` point to a valid memory location for `scanf` to write the result into (technically it needs `rsi` for that, but you load `rsi` from `rdx`). Also your `movzbq (%rdx), %rcx` needs it to be a valid pointer, hopefully to the value read by `scanf`.

Comment: To avoid stack, declare a variable in the `.data` section, e.g. `input: .byte 0` then do `movq $input, %rsi` before `scanf` and `movzbl input, %ecx` afterwards.

Comment: will this work?
movq $char, %rdi
subq $1, %rsp   
movq %rsp, %rsi    
xor %rax, %rax    
call scanf    
movzbq (%rsp), %rdx

Comment: Logically, yes. Technically, no. You don't want to misalign the stack pointer. Subtract 8 (or 16 depending on previous stack alignment) even though you only need 1 byte. Also remember to free that space later.

Comment: sorry forgot to inc1 my rsp.
But my original intention was will it work even though rdx is caller saved?

Comment: Is your format string called `$char` because you want a single character?  If so, call `getchar()` instead of `scanf()`, and the result will be in EAX.  (The whole 32 bits are significant: check for `eax == -1` to detect EOF, otherwise you have a valid character.)

Comment: "rdx is caller saved" means, that you are free to modify it, if you want to load it with some value, and you don't need to restore it to original value. And the same goes with `scanf`, if you had some important value in `rdx` before `call scanf`, you have to preserve it somehow (write it into memory, or copy it to register which will be preserved, or reload it after `scanf` again if it's compile time constant), as the `scanf` is free to modify `rdx` (and it very likely *will* modify it). These things are easy to catch with debugger (often marks registers with modified values after each step).

Comment: FWIW, don't forget to check the value returned (in %rax, I guess) by scanf. It should be the number of values read. If that is only one, it should return 1 (and thus not be 0).